# How to select an element by refrencing the inside element of a nested class

Tags: css

For this html code, I want to select an element using CSS.
I need to select "Cvv2 required" by referencing validatedMessage. I was thinking of trying .validateMessage + .Cvv2.required .However, that didn't work. It seems "Cvv2 required" is after "CCNumber required". But I need to reference "validatedMessage" which is inside  "CCNumber required". I don't even know thats the proper jargon to explain this relationship....

```
<div class="CCNumber required">
   <label id="label">Credit Card Number:</label>
      <input name="test" type="text" class="wrong">
         <span class="validatedMessage">Required</span> <br>
</div>
<div class="Cvv2 required">
    <a> What's this</a><br>
</div>
```

Comment: What programming language? You have shared some html, and tagged your post with css. Do you want a css selector? It is very hard to understand what you are after. Perhaps you should give it a min, and try to rephrase your question.

Comment: I am trying to select the Cvv2 required using CSS. The hard part is it needs to reference validatedMessage which is inside CCNumber required.

Comment: What do you mean by it needs to be referenced? Perhaps it would help if you explain the purpose of your code. Or a visual representation maybe?

Comment: You cannot select "neighbours" based on a DOM hierarchy. In case you want to select "div.Cvv2.required" based on "div.CCNumber.required is existent", you could do it with Javascript, for example with jQuery. If this would be an option, please describe your problem more detailed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible with pure CSS.

You are looking for some kind of "contains" query, which is not available.

https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/#article-header-id-4